# jQuery image zoom with slider

Tags: jquery, image, slider, zooming, slide

Does anybody know of a jQuery plugin that can do something like this:
http://www.endclothing.co.uk/catalog/product/view/id/5599/s/nike-leather-blazer-vintage-pre-order/category/4/

Im at a dead end.

Thanks,
A.

Answer (score 4):

This plugin looks like it will do what you want:

http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/

Answer (score 0):

This one does exactly as the original poster requested:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/featuredzoomer.htm